# Error message in TensorFlow: "could not open file to read NUMA node" and missing directory in /sys/bus/pci/devices

Tags: tensorflow, wsl-2, cudnn, numa

I am new to ML. So take it easy on me.

I'm using TensorFlow in my project, and every time I run my code, I get the following error message:
`2023-02-23 13:17:55.003041: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:967] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:2b:00.0/numa_node Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.`

The message repeats several times in the console, and also mentions that the kernel may not have been built with NUMA support. However, when I check my /sys/bus/pci/devices directory, I cannot find the directory 0000:2b:00.0 mentioned in the error message. Instead, I see the following directories:
74fd:00:00.0 a5cb:00:00.0 c4db:00:00.0 e718:00:00.0 f908:00:00.0

I am using Windows11/WSL2, tensorflow==2.11, python3.9, cudnn==8.1.0.77, nvidia-cudnn==8.2.0.51, cudatoolkit==11.2.2, nvidia-cuda-nvrtc==11.3.58, nvidia-cuda-runtime==11.3.58

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error message and what I can do to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not an error message, its just informative (see the I at the beginning?).

Comment: How can this message be disabled to not appear anymore?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dr. Snoopy, These are just informational messages which will not interrupt the code execution.

However please verify if you have followed all the [steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) properly to install tensorflow.

Also please install the specific version of CUDA and cuDNN compatible to Tensorflow 2.11 to have GPU support enabled in your system.

Please refer to this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) for the same.
[image]